# marginLeft doesn't seem to be working on my GridLayout

Tags: android, grid-layout

I'm attempting to use a GridLayout in my android app, and I want it to start 160dp over from the left side of the screen. When I set `android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"` I see this happen in the GraphicalLayout tab in Eclipse, but when I build the app, it doesn't reflect that margin.

Am I missing something?

The rest of my GridLayout code:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Comment: who is the parent of this layout? can you give us more details?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, so I'll share what I can...AFAIK, this is the parent. In the xml file, this is the top level element.

Comment: Have you tried to rule this out on a physical Android device rather than the emulator?

Comment: I have not, I don't have one available at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup)
to inflate the layout? If so, did you supply a root view? If you passed in null, all `layout_` attributes will be stripped from your GridLayout.

Comment: when I search for this layout in the code, I do see this line: 
view = inflater.inflate(resId, container, false);
So I am assuming so...